# yaml file for php app on GAE

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml

I am working on a bilingual project and the index.php is a script to get accept language and include the proper file: if language is X, include /x/index.php if language is not X, include /y/index.php. My directories have this structure:

```
_
|-index.php
|
|-static
|
|- x - spanish.php
|    
|_ y - english.php
```

I have no clue about how to configure the yaml file. I have the one below, but it does not load the proper php funcionalities after index.php includes page.php.

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /
  script: index.php
```

I have not idea how to solve it and I would be immensely thankful for any help.

Comment: what is deciding the language? app.yaml rules are first match wins - you have 2 /X and 2 /Y - only the first one will ever match.

Comment: hi. the file that decides the language is the index.php, at the first level. Then, I have a folder for language X and a folder for language Y. And each one of them has static files (I need specific javascript and css files for each language). I don't know how to "translate" the structure of my directories in the yaml file...

Answer (score 1):

Provided the URLs are something like /y/js/file.js and /x/js/file.js then all you need is

```
- url: /y
  static_dir: y

- url: /x
  static_dir: x
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. However, to avoid conflict with the URLs, I changed the structure of my directories. I put all the static files inside one single folder. CSS, JS and images are loading beautifully. But not the PHP. I enter myapp.appspot.com and it includes the right file (spanish.php, for instance). But none of the PHP funcionalities of this spanish.php file work...(I updated my post with the new structure).

Comment: probably better to ask a new question then